# In Haskell, what's does the notation >.> represent?

Tags: haskell

What does the notation `f >.> g = g . f` mean?  Specifically what does the two `>` symbols around the dot indicate?

Comment: From what I've seen, the convention for using double `>` indicates a sort of "direction". You could read this is as feed the result of `f` into `g`, which is sort of the "opposite direction" of function composition.

Comment: `>.>` is an indivisible operator symbol. It represents a function. Its individual characters represent nothing, just like `r` in `print` represent nothing. In Haskell you can define new operator symbols. You can define `>.>` or `+++<>+++` or `>>><<<` or `-=+=-` to do whatever you want. Some library happens to define `f >.> g ` to be the same as `g . f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the name of an operator; the operator might as well have been named `foo` or `>>>>.>` or something else, as long as its a legal name in Haskell.

A domain specific meaning of the symbols might have been assigned by the author, especially in relation to other names in the same library, however, in this case, I doubt there is some deeper meaning — it's just the reverse function composition operator.

Comment: If it _is_ a reverse composition operator (which should be determined with `:t (>.>)` in GHCi) then it should be noted that it's preferrable to use [`>>>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-62--62--62-) from the base library instead.